# Displaying posts that belong to a specific author

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, tags

I am a drupal developer who is trying help out a friend with this task. I have a custom team post that has all the team members of the company and they sometimes post an article about their cases. If the user creates a post it gets a link of:

[image]

and I want to direct user to the post page that is going to direct to a page dynamically and display the posts that this team member has.

I tried to do this with pre_get_posts but unfortunately no luck.

Afterwards I thought I could apply drupal's taxonomy logic on this and i created taxonomy name "Author-Team" and I can tag authors to individual posts. This is how i created the taxonomy:

```
 add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );
 function build_taxonomies() {
   register_taxonomy(  'author-team', 'post',   //Let WordPress know that the artist taxonomy has posts
   array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'label' => 'Author-Team', // This tells WordPress how to label the various user interface outlets for the artist taxonomy
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'author-team', 'with_front' => false))
   );
}
```

Then I created taxonomy template name taxonomy-author-team.php and created a dummy post and tagged it via author name 'tom', and when i go to the url of:

```
   example.com/taxonomies/?author-team=tom
```

it shows page not found(For your information taxonomy-author-team.php has only "hello world" in the template). I know I am  making a logical mistake somewhere but i just couldnt figure it out even though I spend hours on it. Can anyone who accomplished this already point me what I am doing wrong or give me a better structural approach for this?

Comment: If the team members really are WordPress "users" you can use the default Author.php template / functions. Use the get_author_posts_url() function to link to to the page where that user's posts will all be displayed: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Michelle. Unfortunately team members are custom post type not WP "users".

Comment: NP, glad you got the right response below. And yes, it will be the taxonomy-author-team.php template you need to edit.

Answer (score 2):

After setting a taxonomy/post_type you firstly need to flush the rewrite rules. To achieve this you could either run `$ wp rewrite flush` if you have installed the [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org) or go to "Settings->Permalinks" and save once. To list a taxonomy in the frontend the url would be `example.com/author-team/tom`. You could also access the taxonomy url via backend "Post->Author-Team" and then hover over a taxonomy. In the quick menu will be a link "view".

Comment: Ok it looks like /author-team/tom is working, but I am not sure what template i should modify to see the results. Is it going to be taxonomy-author-team.php? Thank you very much for the quick response btw.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) you can see the template structure ([full reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies)). If a variable template exists this one will be displayed. If you are using the link `example.com/author-team/tom` the taxonomy archive is called. So `taxonomy-author-team.php` should work. If you want to be more precise you could also create `taxonomy-author-team-tom.php`. The files have to be placed in the root of the theme `wp-content/themes/yourtheme`.